# What is blocked when playing the free version of FF14?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I'm trying to read up on what is and what isn't in the free version of Final Fantasy XIV.

So far what I can see that is blocked is

- Level Capped at 60 (so what is the usual cap? is 60 halfway up? 3/4 up the levels?)
- No Free companies (in generic MMORPG terms... what is that?)
- No parties (are they talking about player groups to quest together? that seems like a huge thing to block.)

So what is and isn't blocked in FF14 free trial version? And if you could please translate FF14-terms to generic MMO terms like raids/guilds/pvp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question**

> So what is and isn't blocked in FF14 free trial version?

**Answer**

You can find the details and restrictions of the [trail version on the Square Enix site](https://support.na.square-enix.com/rule.php?id=5382&la=1&tag=freetrial).

Here is the relevant extract:

> The following terms and conditions apply to players who use the Free
> Trial (“Free Trial Players”):
>
> - Free Trial Players are not required to purchase licensed software to use the Free Trial.
> - One (1) Free Trial account may be registered to a Square Enix account so long as that Square Enix account has not been previously
>   registered with any version of the game.
> - Free Trial Players can purchase select in-game items from the FINAL FANTASY® XIV Online Store during the Free Trial. Not all in-game items
>   are available for purchase by Free Trial Players (e.g., in-game item
>   gift codes).
> - Free Trial Players can create up to eight (8) playable characters, restricted to one (1) playable character per World.
> - Free Trial account characters have all their levels capped at level sixty (60).
> - Free Trial account characters can possess a maximum of 300,000 gil (in-game currency).
> - Free Trial Players cannot use the "shout," "yell," or "tell" in-game chat options during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players cannot access the in-game market board during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players cannot trade with other players during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players cannot send in-game letters using the moogle delivery service during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players cannot hire retainers during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players can join a Linkshell or Cross-World Linkshell if invited but cannot create a new Linkshell or Cross-World Linkshell
>   during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players cannot create or join a Free Company during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players can join a party if invited or by using the Duty Finder but cannot assemble a party during the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players cannot create or join a PvP team or participate in The Feast (Ranked Match) or The Feast (Team Ranked Match) during
>   the Free Trial.
> - Free Trial Players cannot log into the Lodestone, the official forum, or Companion application during the Free Trial.

---

**Question**

> so what is the usual cap? is 60 halfway up? 3/4 up the levels?

**Answer**

The current [level cap is 80](https://www.pcgamesn.com/final-fantasy-xiv/ffxiv-leveling-guide-fast-power-max-level-cap). This could change in the future.

---

**Question**

> No Free companies (in generic MMORPG terms... what is that?)

**Answer**

Information can be [found here](https://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Free_Company). Extract:

> Free Companies are player operated organizations similar to guilds in other MMOs. Players can only be in 1 Free Company at a time.

---

**Question**

> No parties (are they talking about player groups to quest together? that seems like a huge thing to block.)

**Answer**

Information can be [found here](https://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/Party). Extract:

> Party is a group of players. Players can form a party to tackle many group activities such as dungeons, trials, FATEs, guildhests, Treasure Hunts and certain quests.

As stated in the list above, you can join parties if invited. You just can't create your own. I disagree that it is a huge thing to block - it's a FREE version, it's supposed to have features missing otherwise nobody would pay for the full version.

Comment: Okay all good, but still, doesn't answer my question. Is 300 000 gil a lot or do by level 60 300000 gil would be 1% of your wealth. What is a free company? What is the true max level? A lot of those things have no wealth if you don't know what you are actually missing out.

Comment: @Fredy31: They sound like different questions to me... come on, I shouldn't be telling you that with your 34k rep! :D

Comment: This question is on a knifes edge. The 1 big question might be too big, but splitting it in small questions would make a bunch of low quality/opinion based questions.

Comment: @Fredy31: So you are trying to bypass the "opinions" rule by bundling them in with another question? I don't come to Arqade much, so perhaps this kind of thing is common and accepted. Although, I think your bullet points questions are valid and can be answered by themselves. 1. What is the level cap in the full game? 2. What are "free companies"? 3. What are parties? Otherwise, your question is basically "is the trial version worth playing, and what am I missing out on?" which is *definitely* asking for opinions.

Comment: @musefan "what am i missing out on" isn't opinionated at all. That seems to be what he's asking, and not directly asking "is it worth playing". What your missing out on would determine if it's worth playing but that's not what's asked

Comment: @Penguin: Well. The list I included does answer "what am I missing out on". It is literally a list of the limitations. i.e. the things you are missing out on.

Comment: @musefan i was merely combatting your point " Otherwise, your question is basically "is the trial version worth playing, and what am I missing out on?" which is definitely asking for opinions " which I still didn't see it as

Comment: @Penguin: Well, you only really picked out part of what I said. If I just meant that part I would have just wrote that part. The first comment from the OP is complaining that it doesn't answer "is 300,000 gil a lot of money"... firstly, that wasn't even in the question so not sure how anyone is supposed to answer that. Secondly, you don't think that's an opinion? Anyway, my whole point is that they are all distinct (and separate) questions. Otherwise, it's just going to end up being a review of the trial version?

Comment: @musefan I did read the whole thing. "Is 300 000 gil a lot or do by level 60 300000 gil would be 1% of your wealth" doesn't sound like an opinion to me. So actually it seems you didn't read the whole thing (or at least cut the quote off and then made it seem opinionated)

Comment: @Penguin: It is, because if you ask 10 different players, you will likely get 10 different answers. It's going to massively vary depending on what you choose to do to get money, and how you spend it. Some players may not even accumulate that much by level 60 if they are shopaholics, others may find it is 80%, or 60%, or 10%... which one is correct? And like I said, that isn't even part of the question, so it's a bit irrelevant discussing it. I have provided an answer (with reference) to the (main) question that was asked. If you don't like my answer, wait for a better one or post your own.

Comment: The is 300k gil thing is yes opinionised, but really what I was looking for was mostly if it was stupid little. Like in Raid Shadow Legends ads they are like 'OH YOU WILL GET 10K IN GAME GOLD! WOW!' The first quests you do in that game give 4k gold. That 10k gold seems big, but in the context of how the economy works in that game, its chump change. Same could be true here. WOW 300k GIL! But a basic potion is 25k Gil. The first quests give 70k gil. So that 300k is nothing.

Comment: @musefan I disagree in that I think that answering how much an amount of currency is worth, like maybe in what it would really get you is still not very opinionated, however I see your point and I think that's fair. Maybe instead of x% of wealth more like what it could buy